# Decode TCP stream captured on WIreshark

Tags: wireshark, tcp

I have captured user and password credentials (in an internal network) sent from my computer to another host in a pcap file.

I thought that I would be able to see the data in cleartext as there are no certificates used in this communication.

So I right click on a random packet and select "Follow TCP Stream" . Of course I can see the header but when it comes to login credentials the data are unreadable as you can see below: 
[image]

Is this something I can decode from the information I get? Thank you

Comment: You are looking at a websocket connection upgrade request. I would suggest, finding out the URL of the POST request (usually) which the webapp makes for authentication and studying that particular request.

Comment: Also, please do NOT take screenshots of text data. It makes it hard to examine. A better way would be to copy the data, paste it in a public paste site (like https://pastebin.com/) and sharing the link here.